# Why is my nullish-coalascing operators not transpiled by the rollup plugin for babel?

Tags: babeljs, rollup, babel-preset-env, nullish-coalescing

I have a svelte project that I would like to transpile nullish-coalascing operators (es2020) to es5 using the rollup plugin `@rollup/plugin-babel` which is [enabled by default  in `@babel/preset-env` since babel v7.6.3](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.6.3).

However in my project it does not work. I have a nullish-coalascing operator in a script tag in a component like this:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    let aCool;
    let canio;
    const increment = () => {
        if (count % 6 === 0) {
            canio = 1;
        }
        count += 1;
        aCool = canio ?? 0;
    };

    console.log('aCool', aCool);
</script>
```

A minimal svelte project can be found [here](https://github.com/cascading-jox/babel-rollup-nullish-coalescing).

Babel seems to run and add the polyfills from core-js but it does nothing with the `??` operator. Why is it not transpiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason why it does not work is because I forgot to set `.svelte` as a file extension that Babel should transpile in the [rollup plugin](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#extensions) hence it doesn't even look at the svelte code. Thanks @JLHwung!!

Comment: Thank you so much for writing the answer despite it being your own question, it just helped me a ton!

Comment: @J.N. I'm really glad it did! Comments like yours makes me want to continue contributing :)